# Karaf is unable to resolve bundle depending on ActiveMQ feature due to multiple Joda-Time versions

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic, apache-karaf

My bundle has a transative bundle dependency on Joda-Time 2.x and gets deployed via a Karaf (3.0.3) feature file. It deployed just fine until I added dependencies to the `activemq-broker` (5.11.1) and `activemq-camel` features delivered with Karaf. My bundle now fails resolution because two paths to the package "org.joda.time" are found. One is the version 2.7 I am depending on, the other is version 1.6 which is a transitive dependency of the ActiveMQ features:

```
Chain 1:
  ch.vivates.ams.pep [152.9]
    import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.joda.time)(version>=2.7.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package=org.joda.time
  joda-time [64.0]

Chain 2:
  ch.vivates.ams.pep [152.9]
    import: (osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.activemq)
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.activemq; uses:=com.thoughtworks.xstream
  org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi [108.0]
    import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.thoughtworks.xstream)(version>=1.4.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package=com.thoughtworks.xstream; uses:=org.joda.time
  org.apache.servicemix.bundles.xstream [118.0]
    import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.joda.time)(version>=1.6.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package=org.joda.time
  joda-time [117.0]
```

I can get my feature to install successfully by explicitly starting the Joda-Time 2.7 bundle before installing the feature:

```
bundle:install -s mvn:joda-time/joda-time/2.7
```

Upon restart of Karaf my bundle fails to start for the same reason and I first have to refresh the Joda-Time 2.7 bundle. Only after that does my bundle start.

What is the "proper" way to solve those issues? Especially the one when re-starting Karaf? I guess I could work around the problem by embedding v2.7 of Joda Time in my own bundle, but that's just a hack.

Currently the feature looks like this:

```
<feature name="name" version="3.0.0-SNAPSHOT" description="description">
        <details>details</details>
        <feature>http</feature>
        <feature>http-whiteboard</feature>
        <feature version="5.11.1">activemq-broker-noweb</feature>
        <feature version="2.14.1">camel-core</feature>
        <feature version="2.14.1">camel-blueprint</feature>
        <feature version="2.14.1">camel-netty4-http</feature>
        <feature version="2.14.1">camel-http4</feature>
        <feature version="2.14.1">camel-jms</feature>
        <feature version="5.11.1">activemq-camel</feature>
        <bundle dependency="true">mvn:my.package/base/3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:my.package/myBundle/3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:joda-time/joda-time/2.7</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.opensaml/2.6.1_3</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6</bundle>
        <bundle>wrap:mvn:org.owasp.esapi/esapi/2.0.1</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.apache.santuario/xmlsec/1.5.6</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15/1.46</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.commons-httpclient/3.1_7</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.commons-collections/3.2.1_3</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.not-yet-commons-ssl/0.3.11_1</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.codehaus.woodstox/woodstox-core-asl/4.4.1</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.codehaus.woodstox/stax2-api/3.1.4</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.herasaf.xacml.core/herasaf-xacml-core/1.0.0.RELEASE</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:net.sf.ehcache/ehcache/2.9.0</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:commons-codec/commons-codec/1.9</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:commons-io/commons-io/2.4</bundle>
</feature>
```

**EDIT:**

This [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-7267) describes the same problem for the Camel Salesforce component. Apparently this was fixed by [widening the version range](https://fisheye6.atlassian.com/browse/camel-git/components/camel-salesforce/camel-salesforce-component/pom.xml?r1=908d7531d681d82805fa7fa54d51866451c80525&r2=738b6097fbe4db00f31dbe3ca18c15cb5a34adb0) of the import to [1.6,3). The ActiveMQ bundle applies the same version range but it still creates problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scenario above is a variation of the problem described in this [blog post](http://blogs.paremus.com/2011/02/solving-osgi-uses-constraint-violations/) by Neil Bartlett. As I have no control over ActiveMQs direct and transitive dependencies the only options I can see are

1. Downgrade my own dependency of Joda-Time to match the version used by xstream
2. [Statically link](http://njbartlett.name/2014/05/26/static-linking.html)/embed Joda-Time 2.7 in my own bundle

I went for option 2).